# Function insertMany has finished without error but nothing was inserted, mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am inserting data in batches of 1000.

I have this function to take care of the insertion:

```
function insertInBatches(i, dataParsed, RecordModel, callback){
    var numberOfBatches = (Math.floor(dataParsed.length/1000)) + 1;
    console.log("Inserting batch #"+i +" out of: " +numberOfBatches);
    var batchedData = dataParsed.slice(i*1000, (i+1)*1000);
    console.log("Batched data: "+JSON.stringify(batchedData));
    RecordModel.insertMany(batchedData)
    .then(function(mongooseDocuments) {
         console.log("  - Insertion was successful.");
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        callback("Error while inserting data to DB: "+err);
        return;
    })
    .done(function() {
        if (i==numberOfBatches-1){
            // Last iteration, all inserted successfully
            console.log("Insertion of: "+numberOfBatches+" batches was successful.");
            callback(null);
            return;
        }
        // Recursive calling to insert next batch
        console.log("Value of i: "+i);
        insertInBatches(++i, dataParsed, RecordModel);
        return;
    });
}
```

The output log looks like this:

```
Model created. Inserting in batches.
Inserting batch #0 out of: 1
Batched data: [{"SCHID":"config","Priority":3,"DateCreated":"2016-08-04T13:22:04.443Z","Status":"queued","Json":{"EmailAddress":"oto@increase.dk","FirstName":"Ondrej","Age":"22"}},{"SCHID":"config","Priority":3,"DateCreated":"2016-08-04T13:22:04.443Z","Status":"queued","Json":{"EmailAddress":"lfr@increase.dk","FirstName":"Lenka","Age":"23"}}]
  - Insertion was successful.
Insertion of: 1 batches was successful.
```

However when I perform `db.MainRecord.find()` from bash I can't see any results.

My `RecordModel` is: `{SCHID: String, Priority: Number, DateCreated: Date, Status: String, Json: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed};`

Path to db:

```
 generalConfig.dbName = "test";
 generalConfig.recordsCollectionName = "MainRecords";
 generalConfig.schemaDefinition = {SCHID: String, Priority: Number, DateCreated: Date, Status: String, Json: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed};
 generalConfig.RecordSchema = new mongoose.Schema(generalConfig.schemaDefinition);
 generalConfig.RecordModel = mongoose.model(generalConfig.recordsCollectionName, generalConfig.RecordSchema, generalConfig.recordsCollectionName);
```

**EDIT:**

I just had to restart the `mongodb` on the server. No clue why though.

**EDIT2:**

The issue was my stupidity, I did the find on the wrong collection: `MainRecord` instead of `MainRecords`...

Comment: Shouldn't you be looking in `db.MainRecords.find()` instead?

Comment: Omfg, I feel so embarrassed... You're right.

Comment: No worries, we've all done it. Probably best to just delete the question.